# Why is it taking too long to export plotly chart as image .png?

Tags: python, image, plotly, export, png

I'm trying to create a plotly bar chart then export it using kaleido engine, but after 30 mins it doesn't return any output. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong with this?

```
labels = ['A','B','C','D']
values = [11,20,30,40]
colors = px.colors.sequential.GnBu
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=values, y=labels, orientation='h', marker_color='rgba(64,191,180,255)')])
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=600,
    height=400,
    paper_bgcolor=None,
)
fig.update_layout(
    plot_bgcolor='white'
)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_tickfont_size=14,
    barmode='group',
    bargap=0.15, 
    bargroupgap=0.1 
)
fig.show()

fig.write_image('test.png', engine='kaleido')
```

Comment: It works [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Oq2A.png) for me, and it takes less than 1 second (with `#fig.show()` commented out) You probably have a configuration issue.